# How to use htaccess to make profile links look like Facebooks

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, profile

I wonder how I can configure my .htaccess file to render profile pages in this format: firstname.lastname.id.
Sort of the way that Facebooks profile links look like, if anyone knows how to make that, it would be very much appriciated! :)

PS. Sorry for being bad at explaining! I'm Swedish!

Comment: Considering that the .htaccess file itself doesn't support conditional coding, exactly...  You will likely have to bounce the user to a script page that CAN handle that.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Well do you have any suggestions on HOW to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# list of extensions which won't be running the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png|txt|ico)$

# everything else will run index.php file, where you can check your URL string if it matches any of your user profile name
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

then in php:

```
$requestedURL = 'first_name.last_name.23423';

$matches = array();
$res = preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).(\d+)/', $requestedURL, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

where $matches is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "first_name.last_name.23423"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "first_name"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "23423"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I use it in an SQL query? I'm not great at PHP so I don't know :(

Comment: Hello? How do I asign the different arrays to variables?

Comment: $firstName = $matches[1]; $lastName = $matches[2];

Comment: about SQL, you better create another post and include what you have so far

Comment: Thanks man, except how do I prevent profile.php from loading whenever index.php loads? I'm probobly a pain in the a*s but I am not very familiar with htaccess :(